# Subtracting two user input numbers, with a move and display the result

Tags: mips32

I'm new to MIPS and I'm using MARS. I can't get my move right and when I execute it gives me some nuts o number. Here is what I have so far, any help would be appreciated.

```
.data

   message1: .asciiz "Enter the any number to subtract :"
   message2: .asciiz "\nEnter the any number to subtract :"
   n1 :      .word 0
   n2 :      .word 0
   message3: .asciiz  "\nThe subtraction of the two numbers is "

.text 
main:   
li $v0 4        #print out message1
la $a0 message1
syscall

li $v0 5        #read message1 as number1
syscall

sw $v0 n1       #store number

li $v0 4        #print out message2
la $a0 message2
syscall

li $v0 5        #read message2 as number2
syscall

sw $v0 n2       #store number

li $v0 4
la $a0 message3
syscall

lw $t0 n1
lw $t1 n2

sub $t0, $v0, $v0   #   t0 = number1 s1 - number2 s2

li $v0, 1       #   print integer
move $t0, $a0       #   move t0 to a0 

syscall         #   run
```

Comment: Can you format your question properly, as that might help us understand it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is doing well until here `sub $t0, $v0, $v0`.When you subtract you should put the the result in the argument register `$a0`then you can use `move` to put that result in return register `$v0` for printing.

change them as following it will work.

```
sub $t2, $t0, $t1   #   t2 = t0 - t1
move $a0, $t2       #   copy t2 to a0
li $v0, 1           #   print integer
syscall             #
```

Another way of doing this subtraction is that you don't need `.word` and `lw`at all. As following

```
        .data

        message1: .asciiz "Enter the any number to subtract :"
        message2: .asciiz "\nEnter the any number to subtract :"
        message3: .asciiz "\nThe subtraction of the two numbers is "

        .text
        main:
            li $v0 4        #print out message1
            la $a0 message1
            syscall

            li $v0 5        #read message1 as number1
            syscall
            move $t0,$v0    # set $t0 to the content of $v0

            li $v0 4        #print out message2
            la $a0 message2
            syscall

            li $v0 5        #read message2 as number2
            syscall

            move $t1,$v0
            li $v0 4
            la $a0 message3
            syscall

            sub $a0, $t0, $t1   #   t0 = number1 t1 = number2

            li $v0, 1       #   print integer
            syscall         #   run
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips on .word and the help. but mine is printing all the messages but doesn't give the subtracted number it takes an input and program finishes. Any thoughts. Again thank you for helping.

Comment: did you changed those 4 line in the end with the 4 line in the answer?

Comment: yeah I did still nothing

Comment: `Enter the any number to subtract :3

Enter the any number to subtract :2

The subtraction of the two numbers is 1
-- program is finished running (dropped off bottom) --`

it's working in my machine you should find out why because the code is working.

Comment: yeah its working now, but when you go above 5 subtract any number it fails or = 0.0 did I miss something to make it do higher math? Again thanks for taking the time to help me with.

Comment: Okey you are right.That's because we used argument register `$a0` and that take only up to 5 argument, I update my answer check it again.  use this code instead `sub $t2, $t0, $t1  
 move $a0, $t2  
 li $v0, 1   
 syscall`

Comment: you're welcome glad it helped, Since you are new in the stackoverflow community, Thanks are actually in material way in stackoverflow community, if one got some answer useful then can vote on or accept an answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44665957/checking-if-a-number-is-greater-then-or-less-then-using-slt-and-branching-using

Answer (score 0):

After the product of (a, b) two numbers in the memory and the result are subtracted from the number (c) in the register, if the number is less than 0, write the MIPS instructions to continue the operation by subtracting 1 from the result, if the number is less than 1000 (DUR) reg. the question is which page can we find