# checking If a number is greater then or Less then using slt and branching using mars

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32, mars-simulator

So this is what i have so far I am not sure where to go from here to branch off or just print out the answer. I tried to print out the message but to no avail. Is there a way to use both slt and branching?

```
.data
    message1: .asciiz "The number is less than. :"
    message2: .asciiz "/nThe number is greater than. :"

.text
    main:
    addi $t0, $zero, 20
    addi $t1, $zero, 5

slt $s0, $t0, $t1
beq $s0, $zero, printmessage1

sge $s0, $t0, $t1
beq $s0, $zero, printmessage2 


li $v0, 10
syscall

printmessage1:
li $v0 4        #print out message1
la $a0 message1
syscall

printmessage2:
li $v0 4        #print out message1
la $a0 message2
syscall
```

Comment: @adam would you have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `slt $t1,$t2,$t3` Set less than : If `$t2` is less than `$t3`, then set `$t1` to 1 else set `$t1` to 0.

One solution that is very easier and reduce the use of instruction is
to use `blt` or `bgt`

> `bgt $t1,$t2,label`  Branch if Greater Than : Branch to statement at label if `$t1` is greater than `$t2`
>
> `blt $t1,$t2,label`      Branch if Less : Branch to statement at label if `$t1` is less than `$t2`

```
    .data
    message1: .asciiz "The number is less than. :"
    message2: .asciiz "/nThe number is greater than. :"

    .text
    main:
    addi $t0, $zero, 20
    addi $t1, $zero, 5

    blt $t0, $t1,printmessage1
    b printmessage2


    li $v0, 10
    syscall

    printmessage1:
    li $v0 4        #print out message1
    la $a0 message1
    syscall

    printmessage2:
    li $v0 4        #print out message1
    la $a0 message2
    syscall
```

Comment: This still prints both messages on `a<b`, falling through into the other print from the syscall.  The question was correctly using `slt`, although they strangely wanted `ge` as the opposite condition, despite their messages saying less or greater, not greater-or-equal.  I guess the point of this question and answer is that `sgt` and `sge` don't exist, but of course `sgt` can be done by reversing the operands to `slt`.  And yes, as you show, a GE branch is just the fall-through case of `slt`/`bne` or `blt`.